# CakePHP: using several tables with one model

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following database tables:

- emails
- crawler_website
- crawler_blacklist

Since these are so close connected I want to create **one** model that uses all of these.

Is this possible in CakePHP? And if so how?

Comment: You might be misunderstanding the concept of models. Each model represents only one single table. BUT you can use related models (and thus tables) in your model. So the answer is: Yes.

Comment: If something using three database tables only requires one model, then I think you’ve not modelled your data as well as you could have. Explain what you’re doing and we may be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add relations between models in cakephp by association.

[Here's the reference page](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Good luck!

Comment: Also this would require me to connect them using ID which has no relevance to what i am doing..

Comment: You're asking about linking database tables together, this is the cakephp way of doing so. If you dislike creating model files, you could consider choosing a different framework.